# directmail, tc_directmail and newsletter extensions not working

Tags: email, typo3

On one TYPO3 installation I have strange problem with **directmail**, **tc_directmail** and **newsletter** extensions. When I try to send a newsletter I get these errors:

- **directmail:**

  `The HTML content could not be fetched`
- **tc_directmail:**

  `Content too short. The content must be at least 200 chars long to be considered valid.`

On the same server other TYPO3 installations and newsletter extensions are working fine.

- `allow_url_fopen` is on
- `allow_url_include` is off

Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

solved, it was not a directmail, or TYPO3 problem, server was not responding for calls from localhost :(

Comment: Just a qq. Is there anyway to build a list in directmail from an sql table other than tt_address?

Comment: you can import mails from, plain text file or use fe_users table